# Updating fields from two tables of Sql CE in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables in Stock.sdf database called:

```
PRODUCT (pid, pname, unitprice)
SALES (pid, qty, totalprice)
```

I want to add the totalprice to SALES table by using update query. Because I want to store the data permanently, whenever a new sales is added.

```
 SALES.totalprice = (SALES.qty * PRODUCT.unitprice WHERE SALES.pid = PRODUCT.pid);
```

I have tried as follows and got Parsing error. What is the possible solution

```
try
            {
                StockDbConnection dbcon = new StockDbConnection();
                SqlCeConnection Conn = new SqlCeConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection("ConnString"));
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("Update a set a.tPrice=@QTY * b.uprice from SALES  a join PRODUCT b on @PID=b.pid", Conn);
                command.Parameters.Add("@QTY", txtQty.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@PID", cmbPid.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data is upated successfully.");
            }

            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }
```

Comment: No, don't store computed values, you'll only get data inconsistency. Use a view instead, that always will return the correct value. (If really required to store these values, do it with triggers.)

Comment: yes I want to store it permanently.

Comment: are you want update query ??

Comment: Yes I want to use the Update query.

Comment: Quantity and PID is prompt from user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
Update a
set a.totalprice=a.qty * b.unitprice
from SALES  a
join product b on a.pid=b.pid
```